# undefined method `name' for "RubyInline":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to setup a rails app and getting following error. Any ideas?

```
b/tasks instead. (called from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
** Invoke gems:install (first_time)
** Invoke gems:base (first_time)
** Execute gems:base
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `name' for "RubyInline":String
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:277:in `=='
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `==='
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `matching_specs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `find_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:410:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:409:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:75:in `add_load_paths'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/var/www/kwikkopy/config/environment.rb:9
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/tasks/gems.rake:17
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: What command did you run? Gem install?

Comment: String doesn't have a method called `name` (the error is quite clear). Try testing your code :)

Comment: rake gems:install --trace rails 2.3.5, the code (not mine) works on another server, I'm trying to setup new server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just hit this myself.   It seems we both fell into gem version hell.   Turns out this is actually a [bug in rails 2.3.11](https://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=29266&group_id=126&atid=575).    The fix is upgrade to 2.3.12.  You'll also need a new rdoc and rake

```
gem install -v=2.3.12 rails
gem install rdoc --version=2.4.3
gem update rake
```

Worked for me.   Good Luck